# как получить id объекта загруженного через ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

собственно грузим  `worksallmenu.html` в контейнер

```
 .co34

jQuery(function ($) { 
$('.m4').on('click', call); 
    function call() { 
        var msg = $('.co34').serialize(); 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'ajax/worksallmenu.html', 
            data: msg, 
            success: function(data) { 
            $('.co34').html(data);  
            }, 
            error: function(xhr, str){ 
            alert('ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode); 
            } 
        }); 
    } 
});
```

как присвоить событие элементу который загрузится?

(писать скрипт в загружаемый html - не вариант)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".co34").on("click", "selector for dynamically loaded element", function(e) { ... });
```

Comment: спасибо, работает. попутал старый .click()